# como validar inputs "time" hora inicial y hora final que la final sea mayor que la inicial

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

tengo un formulario con mas elementos pero solo extraí los que son referentes a mi duda, les comento... tengo un input date (fecha), input time (hora inicial) y input time (hora final) y es el siguiente:

```
<form role="form" name="guardar-reunion" id="guardar-reunion" method="post" action="../Modelos/modelo_reunion.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
        <input required style="width: 40%;" type="date" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="fecha" name="fecha" min="<?php echo $hoy; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="horainicio">Hora Inicio: </label>
        <input required style="width: 30%;" type="time" class="form-control" id="horainicio" name="horainicio">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="horafinal">Hora Final: </label>
        <input required style="width: 30%;" type="time" class="form-control" id="horafinal" name="horafinal">
    </div>
</form>
```

en el input fecha ya lo valide poniendole en min la fecha actual mediante PHP de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$dtz = new DateTimeZone("America/Mexico");
$dt = new DateTime("now", $dtz);
$hoy = $dt->format("Y-m-d");   
?>
```

y en el min del input le puse:  `min="<?php echo $hoy; ?>"`

y hasta aquí todo bien porque no me deja seleccionar un día anterior, mi pregunta es como hago
para validar que no se pueda seleccionar una hora final menor que la inicial y si se selecciona en fecha el día actual no deje seleccionar hora menor que esta actualmente ya sea con javascript, jquery, ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objeto `Date()` tiene un propiedad [.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) que:

> es un número de milisegundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970 00:00:00 UTC

Osea que cualquier fecha y hora de cualquier zona horaria se pueden comparar entre si ( usando `>`, `<` o `===` ) usando esos milisegundos, que es un entero simpre relativo a lo mismo, osea que es comparable.

Entonces lo que tienes que hacer en mi opinion es crear un `Date` de todo lo que quieras comparar y luego hacer el `.getTime()` para hacer comparaciones:

```js
const inicio = document.getElementById("horainicio");
const final = document.getElementById("horafinal");


const comparaHoras = () => {

  const vInicio = inicio.value;
  const vFinal = final.value;

  if (!vInicio || !vFinal) {
    return;
  }

  const tIni = new Date();

  const pInicio = vInicio.split(":");

  tIni.setHours(pInicio[0], pInicio[1]);

  const tFin = new Date();

  const pFin = vFinal.split(":");

  tFin.setHours(pFin[0], pFin[1]);


  if (tFin.getTime() > tIni.getTime()) {

    console.log("final mayor a inicio");

  }

  if (tFin.getTime() < tIni.getTime()) {

    console.log("final menor a inicio");

  }

  if (tFin.getTime() === tIni.getTime()) {

    console.log("Iguales");

  }


}

inicio.addEventListener("change", comparaHoras);
final.addEventListener("change", comparaHoras);
```

```html
<form role="form" name="guardar-reunion" id="guardar-reunion" method="post" action="../Modelos/modelo_reunion.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
    <input required style="width: 40%;" type="date" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="fecha" name="fecha" min="<?php echo $hoy; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="horainicio">Hora Inicio: </label>
    <input required style="width: 30%;" type="time" class="form-control" id="horainicio" name="horainicio">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="horafinal">Hora Final: </label>
    <input required style="width: 30%;" type="time" class="form-control" id="horafinal" name="horafinal">
  </div>
</form>
```

En este caso comparamos horas del dia actual, no del día seleccionado, pero eso entiendo que es irrelevante, porque en cualquier caso lo importante es que las fechas sean la misma, no importa cual.

Comment: y como hago para impedir si la fecha final es mayor enviar los datos por post?